# Using beforeEach in webdriver-io

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, webdriver-io

I'd like to know how to use a beforeEach in webdriver-io. I am testing a CMS and want to be able to login before every test and think a beforeEach would be good, however this doesn't work. The terminal says that there is an error and the element cannot be found. I basically want it to log me in everytime without having to write browser.login().

```
browser.addCommand('login', function () {
    return this
        .url('/admin/index.php')
        .setValue('[name="username"]', 'foo')
        .setValue('[name="password"]', 'bar')
        .click('[name="login"]');
});
```

that is my login command.

```
beforeEach(function(){
     browser.login();
});
```

this is my beforeEach.

I have also have tried to return the function call as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could save your login steps as a *helper* method.

```
module.exports = function *() {
  // steps required for successful login
}
```

Then call this *helper* method e.g.

```
'use strict';

import loginHelper from '../path/login_helper.js';

describe ('...', () => {
  beforeEach(function *() {
    yield* loginHelper();
  });

  it('...', function *() {
    // steps
  });
});
```

Comment: Ok but you would have to use the loginHelper(); every time I wanted to login in every single it block as you've deminstrated. How would I use this with a beforeEach? Is there a way to do this in ES 5?

Comment: I cannot speak on the implementation in ES5 but it would be a simple update to use the hook to run the `login` procedure.